# Why line plot (ggplot2) is producing vertical lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I am trying to make a lineplot for sales across years for different states, but only getting zigzags no matter whatever solution I try from questions asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74033203/why-does-my-line-plot-ggplot2-look-vertical). Here is the code I used:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = sales, group = location, color = location)) +
    geom_line()  +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

So I'd really apreciate if you could help me detect the issue here. Please see dput of data below.

```
                         location         age year  sales
1          South-East Asia Region   <20 years 2002 0.01
2      Western Sub-Saharan Africa 20-24 years 2010 0.04
3      Commonwealth Middle Income 40-44 years 2003 0.18
4                  Eastern Europe 45-49 years 2008 0.37
5  World Bank Lower Middle Income   <20 years 2005 0.01
6                         Oceania 45-49 years 2006 0.26
7      Commonwealth Middle Income 55-59 years 2004 0.30
8      Western Sub-Saharan Africa 30-34 years 1997 0.04
9        High-income Asia Pacific 65-74 years 2000 0.24
10                      Caribbean 55-59 years 2008 0.33
11           Andean Latin America   75+ years 2019 0.28
12                 Eastern Europe 40-44 years 1998 0.25
13   North Africa and Middle East 30-34 years 2009 0.18
14                 Eastern Europe   <20 years 2015 0.02
15         Western Pacific Region 25-29 years 2001 0.11
16        Sub-Saharan Africa - WB 20-24 years 2012 0.04
17                         Africa 20-24 years 2002 0.03
18     Western Sub-Saharan Africa 55-59 years 1997 0.20
19    Southern Sub-Saharan Africa 50-54 years 2014 0.12
20                           Asia 45-49 years 2019 0.30
21         World Bank High Income 65-74 years 2000 0.35
22                 African Region    All ages 1992 0.10
23     Commonwealth Middle Income   <20 years 1993 0.01
24     Western Sub-Saharan Africa 50-54 years 1993 0.19
25                 Western Europe   75+ years 1993 0.53
26                 Central Europe 25-29 years 2013 0.09
27         South-East Asia Region 40-44 years 2014 0.23
28        Sub-Saharan Africa - WB 55-59 years 2006 0.18
29        Commonwealth Low Income    All ages 1999 0.11
30     Eastern Sub-Saharan Africa 30-34 years 2010 0.02
31                        Oceania 25-29 years 2019 0.14
32                      Caribbean 40-44 years 2003 0.16
33                European Region 55-59 years 2002 0.37
34     Central Sub-Saharan Africa   80+ years 2013 0.41
35 World Bank Upper Middle Income 20-24 years 1996 0.09
36         Southern Latin America 55-59 years 2005 0.30
37                        America    All ages 1994 0.32
38          World Bank Low Income   <20 years 1993 0.01
39         Southern Latin America 65-74 years 1998 0.35
40 World Bank Upper Middle Income 60-64 years 1998 0.39
41   Eastern Mediterranean Region 35-39 years 2006 0.22
42                European Region 35-39 years 2008 0.21
43                     South Asia   80+ years 2010 0.32
44        Sub-Saharan Africa - WB 50-54 years 2001 0.16
45           Andean Latin America 55-59 years 1993 0.22
46         Tropical Latin America 45-49 years 2005 0.30
47        Sub-Saharan Africa - WB 50-54 years 2002 0.13
48         World Bank High Income 40-44 years 2007 0.20
49   North Africa and Middle East 25-29 years 2011 0.11
50   Eastern Mediterranean Region 65-74 years 1993 0.48
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that produced that graph, please? `pct` (in the y axis) is not a variable in your data.

Comment: Also, `"East Asia"` is not in your data.

Comment: Those vertical lines usually indicate the omission of a `group` aesthetic.

Comment: @RuiBarradas pct was renamed from salesPercentage. I just added the code along with the data.

Comment: That's not the output of a `dput` call FYI. Part of what's useful about calling `dput` rather than pasting a text representation of your data is that it retains data types. It's hard to tell from this sample but it seems like you probably have multiple groups (age groups I guess) per location—what did you want / expect to do with them?

Comment: @camille Thank you for the clarification. Yes, there are other factor columns in the data, but the goal is to plot sales by location for over the years.

Comment: In the sample you posted, there are 2 values of Western Sub-Saharan Africa for 1997—they have different age groups. Your plot looks like that's the case for many or all of your locations. The vertical lines happen from trying to plot 2 points for the same group. Those are the cases I asked about—what did you want to happen there?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `group()` only to `year` or `location`, which results in `year` containing `pct` values in different `locations`.

For example:
The data in 2002 contains 0.01 of South-East Asia Region and 0.13 of Sub-Saharan Africa - WB.

Can you provide your `ggplot2` code if it is convenient?

I did a small test with `mtcars`, where the `gear` and `carb` of mtcars have been factored.

```
mt %>% 
group_by(gear,carb) %>% 
mutate(mean=mean(disp)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(gear,mean,group=carb,color=carb))
+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]
Can this help you?

Comment: Thank you for the exmaple. I used similar code to this one, so it didn't help much.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit I'm sorry my answer wasn't able to help you. As I answered above, there may be different values of `pct` included in the same group. I think there are no problems with the code of `ggplot2`. For example, because of a miscalculation, in 2002 East Asia included both 0.2 and 0.8, which caused the two points to be connected as a vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

With your data,

```
df <- data.frame(
  location = c("South-East Asia Region","Western Sub-Saharan Africa",
    "Commonwealth Middle Income","Eastern Europe","World Bank Lower Middle Income",
    "Oceania","Commonwealth Middle Income"   ,"Western Sub-Saharan Africa"   ,"High-income Asia Pacific"   ,
    "Caribbean"   ,"Andean Latin America","Eastern Europe"  ,"North Africa and Middle East"   ,
    "Eastern Europe"   ,"Western Pacific Region","Sub-Saharan Africa - WB","Africa",
    "Western Sub-Saharan Africa"   ,"Southern Sub-Saharan Africa"   ,"Asia"   ,"World Bank High Income"   ,
    "African Region" ,"Commonwealth Middle Income"   ,"Western Sub-Saharan Africa","Western Europe" ,
    "Central Europe"   ,"South-East Asia Region"   ,"Sub-Saharan Africa - WB"   ,"Commonwealth Low Income" ,
    "Eastern Sub-Saharan Africa","Oceania"   ,"Caribbean"   ,"European Region"   ,
    "Central Sub-Saharan Africa" ,"World Bank Upper Middle Income"   ,"Southern Latin America"   ,"America" ,
    "World Bank Low Income"   ,"Southern Latin America"   ,"World Bank Upper Middle Income","Eastern Mediterranean Region"   ,
    "European Region"   ,"South Asia","Sub-Saharan Africa - WB"   ,"Andean Latin America"   ,"Tropical Latin America"   ,
    "Sub-Saharan Africa - WB"   ,"World Bank High Income"   ,"North Africa and Middle East"   ,"Eastern Mediterranean Region"
  ),
  age = c(
    "<20 years", "20-24 years","40-44 years","45-49 years","<20 years",
    "45-49 years","55-59 years","30-34 years","65-74 years","55-59 years",
    "75+ years","40-44 years","30-34 years","<20 years","25-29 years",
    "20-24 years","20-24 years","55-59 years","50-54 years","45-49 years",
    "65-74 years","All ages"  ,"<20 years","50-54 years","75+ years",
    "25-29 years","40-44 years","55-59 years","All ages"  ,"30-34 years",
    "25-29 years","40-44 years","55-59 years","80+ years"  ,"20-24 years",
    "55-59 years","All ages","<20 years","65-74 years","60-64 years",
    "35-39 years","35-39 years","80+ years"  ,"50-54 years","55-59 years",
    "45-49 years","50-54 years","40-44 years","25-29 years","65-74 years"
  ),
  year = c(2002,2010,2003,2008,2005,2006,2004,1997,2000,2008,
            2019,1998,2009,2015,2001,2012,2002,1997,2014,2019,
            2000,1992,1993,1993,1993,2013,2014,2006,1999,2010,
            2019,2003,2002,2013,1996,2005,1994,1993,1998,1998,
            2006,2008,2010,2001,1993,2005,2002,2007,2011,1993),
  sales = c(0.01,0.04,0.18,0.37,0.01,0.26,0.30,0.04,0.24,0.33,0.28,
             0.25,0.18,0.02,0.11,0.04,0.03,0.20,0.12,0.30,0.35,0.10,
             0.01,0.19,0.53,0.09,0.23,0.18,0.11,0.02,0.14,0.16,0.37,
             0.41,0.09,0.30,0.32,0.01,0.35,0.39,0.22,0.21,0.32,0.16,
             0.22,0.30,0.13,0.20,0.11,0.4)
)
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y= sales, group=location,
             color=location)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1992,2020,1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Like other comments and answer, you should specify `group` arguments when plotting line plot.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Jang, I did use the groupe aes originally. Strangely, the code works with dput data, but I am still getting the vertical lines when plotting the main data. I added the code to the question.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit Check if `year` was read in as a factor.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit your code still works fine for me with the `dput` data. Seems like your data have some problem. I couldn't help you without your main data. Appreciate if you provide as least some part of your data.